# Android connecting to mysql through php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm new to android and i would like to create an application that reads data from mysql server. [I've taken from web an example about this](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/), but i cannot make it work

I'm using eclipse for this and for the other part, php and mysql.
First of all, here is my php script that is running ok ([city.php](http://steagu.ro/android/city.php)):

```
<?php
//connecting to database
$sql=mysql_query("select * from city");
$output = array();
while(list($id,$name)=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $output[$id]=$name;

}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_free_result($sql);

?>
```

This is returning:

```
{"1":"Brasov","2":"Bucuresti"}
```

On my android project from eclipse, I have in the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.mycity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.net.ParseException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.steagu.ro/android/city.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Server encountered an error.");

     }
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         //e.printStackTrace();
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection: "+e.toString());
    }

  }


}
```

But when I'm running this, I receive an error on logcat:it's not connecting to the file:Error in http connection: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

```
10-24 13:04:34.429: I/dalvikvm(982): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 13:04:34.649: I/dalvikvm(982): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 13:04:34.859: E/log_tag(982): Error in http connection: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-24 13:04:34.919: I/dalvikvm(982): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 13:04:34.949: I/dalvikvm(982): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-24 13:04:35.151: D/gralloc_goldfish(982): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-24 13:04:35.479: I/dalvikvm(982): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-24 13:04:35.499: I/dalvikvm(982): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I have permission for internet in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mycity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know where is the problem. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you checked your internet is working in your emulator ?

Comment: Hi Antarix, yes, the internet connection is working fine in emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an AsyncTask class to carry out your network operations as strictmode does not allow it to be done on the main UI example as follows

```
          public class MainActivity extends Activity {

         JSONArray jArray;
         String result = null;
         InputStream is = null;
          StringBuilder sb=null;

         @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       new httpRequest().execute();

        }


         private class httprRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

                @override
                public String doInBackground(String.... params){
                   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new             ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //http post
          try{
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.steagu.ro/android/city.php");
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
               Log.d("MyApp", "Server encountered an error.");

              }
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          is = entity.getContent();
          }catch(Exception e){
          //e.printStackTrace();
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection: "+e.toString());
           }

                }
              }

           }
       }
```

Comment: in order to fix the new error your receiving change this line in the onCreate method. new httpRequest().execute();
to
result = new httpRequest().execute().get; 
That should fix your errors let me know in another comment or new question. :)

Comment: Thnak you, it works! But this should be put in a try-catch, cause otherwise is giving an error. so the code is like this: try {
result = new httprRequest().execute().get();
} catch (Exception e) {}

int ct_id=0;
String ct_name="";


//wait to have the data inside the variable

while(result == null) {
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
10-24 13:04:34.859: E/log_tag(982): Error in http connection: 
                    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You need to do your network access on a different thread.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you kabuto178, I'm made the changes and it's connecting. I've wrote the code also for retrieving data from mysql, so who need this, can use my example

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.mycity;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.net.ParseException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String result = "";
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;
//String ct_name = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
new httprRequest().execute();


int ct_id=0;
String ct_name="";

//Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is "+result, 3000).show();

try {
Thread.sleep(1000L);
} catch (Exception te) {}

try{
    //ct_name = result;
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
           JSONObject json_data= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           ct_id=json_data.getInt("CITY_ID");
           ct_name += json_data.getString("CITY_NAME")+":";
       }

    }
    catch(JSONException e1){
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }

TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setText(ct_name);

}

private class httprRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override 
    public String doInBackground(String... params){
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.steagu.ro/android/city.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
   Log.d("MyApp", "Server encountered an error.");

  }
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
//e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection: "+e.toString());
}

//convert response to string

try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
       sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

       String line="0";
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Am eroare aici", 3000).show();
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}


/*
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Here i am", 3000).show();
*/

return result;
    }

  }

}
```

I have to change a little bit the code, cause i put a thread.sleep. Instead of it, i have to check if i have a value into result (in a while loop). I think this is happening because at that moment when i try to parse the value, i don;t have a value in result.

The php code is:

```
<?php
//connecting to database
$sql=mysql_query("select * from city where CITY_NAME like '%'");
$output = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $output[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($output);
mysql_free_result($sql);

?>
```

Table 'city' has two columns, CITY_ID and CITY_NAME.